# How to display custom post type ordered by a custom field date

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, order, date

I have a custom post type for a *timeline activities*.

each post of them has a custom field type of **DATE**. field name :`activity-date`

I'm using [TYPES plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) for **Custom Post Type** and **Custom Fields**

I would like to order these posts by the custom date field, I tried the following but didn't work.

```
<?php $activities = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'timeline',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'key'           => 'activity-date',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'ASC'                            
)); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct array key to use is `meta_key`, not *key*. You can only use `key` as part of a `meta_query` subarray, where the 'meta' part is implied.

This is all described in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Try

```
<?php $activities = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'timeline',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'      => 'activity-date',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'ASC'                            
)); ?>
```

Comment: whenever I use 'meta_key' in my wpquery, nothing displays!

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, it appeared that TYPES plugin is storing the meta_key's name like

`'meta_key' => 'wpcf-yourmetakey'`

The solution is :

```
<?php $activities = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         =>  'timeline',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1, 
    'meta_key'          => 'wpcf-activity-date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
    ));
?>
```